# Hierarchical Telerik RadGrids: How can I get rid of sorting bugs?

Tags: sorting, telerik, hierarchy, telerik-grid

I'm using a hierarchical RadGrid (Telerik control) but there are some bugs regarding the sort of the second level. I have two levels and the second level is loaded based on the first level.

Columns of the first level: Foo1, Foo2, Foo3

Columns of the second level: Bar1, Foo2, Bar2, Bar3

Binding is issued through a function.

Problems:

1. If a single row of the first level is expanded (we can see a single sub-grid from the second level) and I want to sort by Bar1, the sort happens, but an error occures:

   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sort' of null
2. If a single row of the first level is expanded (we can see a single sub-grid from the second level) and I want to sort the second level by Foo2, the sort happens for the parent grid's (!) Foo2 column
3. If two rows of the first level are expanded (we can see two sub-grids from the second level) and I want to sort both the subgrids by the same column a strange rectangle appears instead of the ascending/descending sign, I get the same error as described in the first problem but the sorting is not issued.

I would like to get rid of these problems, my question is the following:

If we have a hierarchical RadGrid and both the first and the second level is sortable how can I implement a sort of the second level to be free of bugs?

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: If these are really bugs (and it sounds like they are), you'd be best off talking to the vendor (Telerik) about them.

Comment: These might be my bugs, first I would like to know if somebody managed to create a sortable hierarchical grid where none of these bugs happened. If somebody managed to do this without a problem, it means that the bugs are fixable and I should search for the right direction, but if I can't see anybody who managed to do this, then it might be a bug in Telerik's hierarchical RadGrid, especially if I can see other people who tried to do this and had the same bugs...

Comment: Which of the Telerik grids you have in mind (AJAX, MVC, XAML, Winforms)? Sorting seems to work properly with hierarchy on their live demos (http://demos.telerik.com/), you cannot see only the winforms grid there due to obvious reasons.

Comment: It's true that sorting seems to work properly in the demos, however, my application uses Javascript to send the commands (not the default settings), also, sorting is helped by a function on server side to keep track of the history of sorting. In addition, Telerik's sorting sorts only the current page on default, my application sorts the whole data source. It works for all the RadGrids and there are a lot of RadGrids in the application, the exceptions are RadGrids which are hierarchical of at least two levels and sorting is enabled for at least a column in an inner level.

Comment: OK, so, after a long time interval of trying and not succeeding I've seen that the inner sort actually works if the columns are not automatically generated, but the set of columns is generated at runtime, so I need a solution for automatically generated columns to make the sorting work (to sort out the sort bug). Whenever I try to sort the same column in two different child grids a rectangle appears instead of the sorting icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

The problem is that the columns are automatically generated and hierarchical RadGrids where the columns are automatically generated have a bug in Telerik. When a column is not sorted, its header (th tag) doesn't have rgSorted class and doesn't have an input tag as a child. When the column is sorted, it has an rgSorted class and it has an input inside it. The input has rgSortedAsc or rgSortedDesc class, depending on the sorting direction. So, if I want to solve it I'll have to make a hack, which will be incompatible with future versions. This is painful, because I need the second level of my grid, I need the columns to be automatically generated (the columns are revealed at runtime) and I want to be able to sort them, but, unfortunately the answer to my question is that there is no solution for this bug.

Please view this thread on the Telerik forum:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/hierarchical-radgrid-sorting-problems.aspx#1782047

I hope I've saved some fellow programmers from the torture I've faced.

Thanks for the comments, fellows,
Lajos Arpad.

Comment: I have good news regarding the issue. The Telerik team assured me that this bug will be solved in the future.